# IOS Real time updates won't trigger if app is in background state

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, websocket, hapi

I set up websocket support in my hapi server using nes

Tried it on android and so far the realtime updates is still working even in background state.

The problem is with IOS, realtime update won't trigger when your app is in the background state. How can i make this work

Comment: A lot of these OS settings are there to stop apps being able to do stuff... (like run background updates for example). It wouldn't make sense for an app to be able to override this.

Comment: in Xcode Project -> Capabilities, turn on Background modes

Comment: Hmm... you appear to have edited your question to remove the mention of "Single App Mode". Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS only allows your [app to keep running in the background in some specific cases](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started). Keeping the WebSocket connection is not one of them. In order to achieve this realtime update, your server needs to provide an API which allows the app to fetch the new data, and your app needs to register a background task and do the fetch. For more detail, [you can check the link here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh).